# Selenium: How to execute scripts within the browser?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

My current goal is to execute a script to my selenium browser that declares a var and then using DevTools access the variable in console log.

Here is the conflicting script:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep

chromePath = 'Selenium Injection\chromedriver.exe'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromePath)

driver.get('https://www.google.com')
driver.execute_script(
    "var test = 'Test Now';"
    "return test"
)
```

Upon execution I try to access the test variable and I get an error.

Comment: @ArundeepChohan And how would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the variable to the window scope instead of the function scope

```
driver.execute_script("this.test = 'Test Now'")
```